# What does it mean to "frame an argument"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I have asked this same question on Yahoo! Answers before, but I didn't quite understand the meaning of it. The phrase is used like so: "See how the author framed his argument?; What is he doing up there? Just framing, just framing"

This is such an odd phrase, but my English teacher uses it all the time.

I am more mathematical and logical, so please try to explain it as such.

Comment: To frame :To arrange or adjust for a purpose: The question was framed to draw only one answer.  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Frame

Comment: Short answer: it means 'establishing backstory and context'. A "framing shot" in a movie is the image intended to be carried forward into the story. In math, think of it as establishing boundary conditions and setting parameters for solving a system of PDEs with several thousand variables.

Comment: OED s.v. frame *v.* says nothing about *argument* as direct object. Reference could be either to the manipulation of *frames* in the cognitive scientists' sense, or to overall argument design--a metaphor from house-building--perhaps as summarized in advance in the *partitio* or *divisio* section of the classical oration. Can general reference cover all that?

Comment: @Brian Donovan- I agree this is not a general reference question. My teacher also did use the analogy of framing a house, but that didn't help, nor do I have a good idea of what that means.

Comment: @Josh61- Helpful, but I think I would do better with more examples.